# How to bind viewmodel property to Template property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have collections in ViewModel , in the collections I have properties Name and Color. I need to bind the color property to template fill.x:key="model" is given for ViewModel

In C#:

```
public class Model
{
public string Name;
public Color Color;
}

public ViewModel
{
 public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get; set; }
        public MapViewModel()
        {
            this.Models = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
            this.Models.Add(new Model() { Name = "Prabhu",Color = Colors.Red });
            this.Models.Add(new Model() { Name = "raji",Color = Colors.Green });
            this.Models.Add(new Model() { Name = "Pranov",Color = Colors.Black });
        }

}
```

In XAML:

```
         <DataTemplate>
           <Path   Data="F1M1433.97,-17.992L1401.97,-49.992 1433.97,-81.992 1465.97,-49.992 1433.97,-17.992z"  Fill="{Binding Data.model }/>
         </DataTemplate>
```

Does any converter need to use?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Color is not applied to the path

Comment: Can you provide `MCVE`?

Comment: What's the DataContext of your DataTemplate? How is the template being applied?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<Path   Data="F1M1433.97,-17.992L1401.97,-49.992 1433.97,-81.992 1465.97,-49.992 1433.97,-17.992z"  Fill="{Binding Data.Color }/>
```

It works when Color is binded to Fill

Comment: This would work if Color is a Brush, i.e. `public Brush Color { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Fill` property is of type `Brush`, not `Color`. What you want is either change your `Model.Color` property type to `Brush` or assign a `SolidColorBrush`:

```
<Path ...>
    <Path.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

Also make sure to use properties, not fields:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work. what to bind in Color ? i JUST NEED CORRECT BINDING PATH